# Model diagnostics & Cross-Validation

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, cross-validation

I have some model which I want to cross-validate. I want to use a leave-one-out cross-validation (LOO-CV), as I have only little data. I created a model for all of my data, did model selection and confirmed with model diagnostics that the assumptions of my model are met. I wrote myself some code to validate my model (not really important, see below). But now I wonder if I have to somehow check model diagnostics inside the loop, i.e. for each model of the LOO-CV? Or is it enough that I checked the complete model?

```
# loo-cv validation
all_res <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(data_all)) {

  # subset data
  data_sub <- data_all[-i,]

  # make models
  mod_sub <- glm(y ~ x, data = data_sub)

  # do I have to check model assumptions here?

  # predict
  pred_sub <- predict(mod_sub, newdata = data_all[i,], type = "response")
  res_sub <- pred_sub - data_all$y[i]
  all_res <- c(all_res, res_sub)
}

# calculate mae & rmse
mae_cv <- mean(abs(all_res))
rmse_cv <- sqrt(mean((all_res)^2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But now I wonder if I have to somehow check model diagnostics inside the loop, i.e. for each model of the LOO-CV? Or is it enough that I checked the complete model?

You don't *have to*. For the [verification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verification_and_validation) of model performance you have to test the final model, which you did. (With an overall small data set, nested cross validation may have been a better choice, but a fixed test set is OK, too).

But you may *want to*: checking the candidate surrogate models in the inner (tuning) cross validation allows you to check e.g. whether your tuning is stable or not: did the folds of the inner cross validation return the same hyperparameters or did  they vary a lot? etc.